# Not able to change the value inside div with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with changing values ("xxxx", "yyyy") I have already try:

```
document.querySelector('.sum_1Ux--VGpXx').innerHTML = 'New Value';
```

and

```
document.querySelector('.balance_1EVI0wwOHO').innerHTML = 'New Value';
```

but this way has no effect. Please help, what I'm doing wrong?

[First pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiD8i.png)

[Second pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QT3I9.png)

Comment: Are you using some kind of other libraries to generate the class for the element..??

Comment: That code should work if your HTML in the pictures is correct. Can you please share all of your JavaScript and HTML code to see if e.g. the code is not being run, or similar?

Comment: How, where, and when is this code executed? Are you sure the IDs never change? They look randomly generated. Are you sure the DOM is fully loaded when you execute these snippets of JS and there are no errors in the console?

Comment: Please post text as text, not images

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to check that you're able to target the element..??

Although, using innerHtml to get the text and set the text isn't a good practice.

Try using:

```
document.querySelector('.sum_1Ux--VGpXx').textContent = 'New Value'; 
document.querySelector('.balance_1EVI0wwOHO').textContent = 'New Value';
```

Comment: Yes, but I recieve an "Cannot set properties of null (setting 'textContent')"

Comment: according to the error you mentioned it seems like you're not able to target the element.

it would be better if you can share the html as well as javascript code here.

Comment: <div class="balanceWrapper_leudewwOCD"><div class="balance_1EVI0wwOHO">xxxx</div><small class="currency_v4zqaJ6aVy">UAH</small></div> I need to change value "xxxx" in "balance_1EVI0wwOHO"

Comment: are you using some sort of external library for generating classes..??

Comment: No, script for tampermonkey, Chrome addon, I need to change amount on site